# why loss is so high for 4 inputs 2 outputs function approximation using MLP?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My code is very simple since my understanding is MLP can approximate any function:

```
def build_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='tanh', input_shape=(4, ), name='a'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='tanh'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', name='b')])
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)  
  model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer)
  return model

def train_benchmark_NN(x, y, epochs=10000):
  model = build_model()
  es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20, verbose=0)
  history = model.fit(x, y, batch_size = 1000, epochs=epochs, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=1, callbacks=[es])
  return model, history
```

I tried different number of layers(like[256, 128, 64, 32]), nodes, optimizer, initializer, activation function. I also tried handle the two outputs separately instead of training one model for them together, but the result is bad too. Actually I don't have a decent judge on how heavy my model should be for data like this. I tried training model for some know function with same number of input and output, it's always very hard when the function like 
`y1=math.cos(x1)+math.cos(x2)+math.cos(x3)+math.cos(x4)`.

Can anyone tell me, I should try much heavier model or I did something wrong in my code? or I have to preprocess the data differently? I only normalized it with zscore. Data size is ~6000 in total.

Current results:

```
Epoch 62/10000
4936/4936 [==============================] - 0s 4us/sample - loss: 0.2711 - val_loss: 3.9427
Epoch 63/10000
4936/4936 [==============================] - 0s 4us/sample - loss: 0.2686 - val_loss: 3.9444
Epoch 64/10000
4936/4936 [==============================] - 0s 3us/sample - loss: 0.2661 - val_loss: 3.9457
```

If I change `validation_split` from 0.2 to 0.01,the result became very different:

```
6109/6109 [==============================] - 0s 5us/sample - loss: 0.3729 - val_loss: 0.0589
Epoch 96/10000
6109/6109 [==============================] - 0s 5us/sample - loss: 0.3683 - val_loss: 0.0356
Epoch 97/10000
6109/6109 [==============================] - 0s 5us/sample - loss: 0.3702 - val_loss: 0.0381
i: 0 , err_mean: 2.383471436639142
<matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x7fdbb329d7f0>
```

Although the `val_loss` became much smaller, that probably because the validation size isn't big enough, because when I plot the errors, it still looks same.

Some visualization of the relationships in my data:

inputs are x1-car speed, x2-engine torque, x3-DOC temperature, x4-DPF temperature

outputs are y1-tailpipe CO gas, y2-tailpipe HC gas.

y1 against x1, x2, x3, x4 are shown below:

[image: x1-y1]
[image: x2-y1]
[image: x3-y1]
[image: x4-y1]

Should this be function easy to approximate at all? Thanks!!!

I plotted errors along targets, it seems the model didn't learn at all, because the errors is very correlated to the targets.
[image]

Comment: You need to treat the task as a regression problem. Try using ReLU layers and set the `activation='linear'` in the last layer.

Comment: hi @ShubhamPanchal, it is a regression task. I believe by default the activation function is linear, I tried it too. also tried all activation functions I can find on the keras/tf documentation.